# Repair Windows 11 MICROCODE_REVISION_MISMATCH on dual boot with Linux

Tags: laptop, debian, multi-boot, windows-11

I've recently installed a dual boot of Windows 11 with Debian 12 on my laptop. It was working fine but one time my laptop discharged when I was running windows. When I connected  the charger to my laptop and started the machine Windows crashed showing the code MICROCODE_REVISION_MISMATCH. Debian is still working perfectly fine, but I can't see how to repair my Windows.

My laptop is a Xenia 14 with an i7-1165G7.

Comment: I saw this in Bing  .... The MICROCODE_REVISION_MISMATCH bug check (error code 0x17E) indicates that one or more processors in a multiprocessor configuration have inconsistent microcode loaded. This inconsistency can lead to stability issues and unexpected behavior in the system   ....  In Bing look for ......... Windows 11 MICROCODE_REVISION_MISMATCH

Comment: I've already look it, and I didn't find anything to solve this issue apart of make a clean installation or using the safe mode which I can't acess.

Comment: I don't know what happened.  Ask the manufacturer if you can replace the CPU.